# QTreeWidget Проблема с переносом строк. Не отображается больше 2х переносов

Tags: qt, qtreewidget

Пытаюсь сделать перенос слов (1я колонка) в строке QTreeWidget.
Если делаю через QLabel перенос слов, то при переносе часть текста пропадает (отображаются только первые два переноса) Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы русский текст при переносе слов полностью отображался в строке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTreeWidget>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  QTreeWidget *treeWidget = new QTreeWidget;
  treeWidget->setColumnCount(2);
  treeWidget->setColumnWidth(0, 100);
  treeWidget->setColumnWidth(1, 100);
  treeWidget->setUniformRowHeights(false);

  QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
  QLabel *label = new QLabel("Первая очень длинная строка тут");
  label->setWordWrap(true);
  treeWidget->setItemWidget(item, 0, label);

  QTreeWidgetItem *item2 = new QTreeWidgetItem(treeWidget);
  QLabel *label2 = new QLabel("Вторая очень длинная строка тут");
  label2->setWordWrap(true);
  treeWidget->setItemWidget(item2, 0, label2);

  treeWidget->show();

  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, не "тут", а "здесь", раз уж текст русский, во-вторых, попробуйте увеличить размер ячейки, и увидите весь текст.

Comment: Во-первых Вы дали бесполезный ответ. Именно про увеличение размера я и спрашиваю. Текст всегда разный по длине, и надо увеличивать размер высоты строки, подстраивая под перенесенный текст. Соответственно высота строк будет разной при фиксированной ширине колонки. Во-вторых текст в примере не имеет смысловой нагрузки и сделан для демонстрации на фото, и может быть любым.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы автоматически увеличивался размер ячейки по высоте, чтобы весь текст был доступен для чтения? Даже если он очень-очень длинный?